# Solve 3D convection-dominated PDE with discontinuous coefficient, without tiny mesh

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, finite-element-method

I'm trying to simulate a self-propelled particle diffusing on a disk. The direction of the self-propelled velocity $\vec{v_A}$ doesn't change, while it speeds up at the boundary and slows down at the center.

I'm trying to solve the following diffusion-convection equation:

$\rho=\rho(x,y,v_A)$

$\vec{v_A}=(v_A,0,0)$

$\partial\rho/\partial t+\nabla_{x,y} \cdot(\rho \vec{v_A})+\partial(\rho g(x,y))/\partial v_A=D_t\nabla_{x,y} ^2\rho+D_v\partial^2{\rho}/\partial{v^2}$

$x^2+y^2<1,v_A\in[0,0.5]$

$g(x,y)=0.033,x^2+y^2<0.5;\\g(x,y)=-0.033,0.6^2<x^2+y^2<1;$

Boundary condition: `NeumannValue[0,True]`.

For $D_t=10^{-3}$ and $D_v=10^{-4}$  is small, the solution of it is very unstable.

But, my server computer's memory (700G) is not big enough for me to make tiny mesh.

How shall I optimize my code?

```
simurWall = 29.5;
rWall = 1;
vmax = 15/simurWall;

Ω = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, vmax}}, rWall];
<< NDSolve`FEM`
cylinderMesh = 
  ToElementMesh[Ω, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001, 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.00005];
hMin = Power[Min[Join @@ cylinderMesh["MeshElementMeasure"]], 
   1/cylinderMesh["EmbeddingDimension"]];


Subscript[A, g] = Disk[{0, 0}, 1/simurWall];
Subscript[A, l] = RegionDifference[Disk[], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.6]];
gainf[x_, y_] := 
  Piecewise[{{1/simurWall, {x, y} ∈ Subscript[A, g]}, {-1/
      simurWall, {x, y} ∈ Subscript[A, l]}}];
ContourPlot[gainf[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[]]

Subscript[D, t] = 1/simurWall^2; Subscript[D, v] = 0.0001;
c = {{Subscript[D, t], 0, 0}, {0, Subscript[D, t], 0}, {0, 0, 
    Subscript[D, v]}};
α = {v, 0, gainf[x, y]};

With[{ρ = ρ[x, y, v, t]}, 
  op = D[ρ, t] == Inactive[Div][Inactive[Plus][
      Inactivate[Dot][c, Inactive[Grad][ρ, {x, y, v}]], 
      Inactive[Times][-α, ρ]], {x, y, v}]];
gaussian[x_, y_] := 
  1/(2 Pi σ^2) Exp[-(x^2 + 
         y^2)/(2  σ^2)] /. σ -> 1;
ic = ρ[x, y, v, 0] == gaussian[x - 0.5, y - 0.5];
diffTime = 20;
ufunI = NDSolveValue[{op, ic}, ρ, {t, diffTime, 
    diffTime}, {x, y, v} ∈ cylinderMesh];
picture = 
  ContourPlot[ufunI[x, y, 0.1, 1], {x, y} ∈ Disk[], 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   ColorFunction -> "WatermelonColors"];
```

Comment: What do you try to simulate?

Comment: I'm trying to simulate a self-propelled particle diffusing on a disk. The direction of the self-propelled velocity doesn't change, while it speeds up at the boundary and slows down at the center.

Comment: Could you, please, give some reference for this model?

Comment: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Brownian_particle)  And I modified the equation by adding acceleration to the particle. thanks

Comment: You mentioned the solution is unstable, but in what manner? Also, how much RAM is needed to test the sample? These should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: Introduction to convection-dominated PDE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423985/58219

Comment: Thanks for you help. I've read the document and set my mesh size tiny enough to make sure $Pe<$mesh order. But it is still unstable. I think there is something wrong with  other settings.

Comment: Sincerely thanks for your help, I'm now trying to solve it by using streamline upwind Petrov Galerkin (SUPG). If there is any progress, I'll upgrade the question.

Comment: I am curious, did you make any progress?

Comment: Thanks for your all's help, but I give up the problem.